# Spring Integration: Error handling for Jpa Outbound Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

i have a Spring Integration flow that uses Jpa.inboundAdapter() as a source, manipulates the read entities in transform and finally stores them again using Jpa.outboundAdapter.

However, during persisting exceptions may occure (Unique Constraint Violation). In that case, the flow kind of "hangs", as it reads from source in a specified order, immediately triggering the same order.

How can I properly do error handling to mark or skip "bad" entities read from source?

The flow:

```java
IntegrationFlows
  .from(
     Jpa
      .inboundAdapter(entityMaanger)
      .entityClass(...)
      .nameqQuery(...)
      .get()
  )
  .split()
  .transform( ..)
  .handle(
     Jpa
       .outboundAdapter(entityManager)
       .entityClass(...)
       .persistMode(MERGER)
       .flush(true)
       .get(),
     e -> e.transactional())
   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move `transactional()` to the `poller()` configuration of the source polling channel adapter for that `Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityMaanger)`.

Right now it looks like you rely on default poller (probably auto-configured by Spring Boot), but you would need to have a second arg on that `from()`:

```
IntegrationFlows
  .from(
     Jpa
      .inboundAdapter(entityMaanger)
      .entityClass(...)
      .nameqQuery(...),
     e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000).transactional())
  )
```